# Query MySQL using data from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can you perform a WHERE query in MySQL using a value found in a specific cell

for example if you have a table full of people and it has the columns first name, middle name, surname perform a SELECT WHERE which finds a single person and then use that persons middle name to find all people with that middle name as their last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub queries to find the person of the middle name but inside the WHERE clase of another query this is an example of code

SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE SALARY > 4500) ;

> A Subquery or Inner query or a Nested query is a query within another SQL query and embedded within the WHERE clause.

> A subquery is used to return data that will be used in the main query as a condition to further restrict the data to be retrieved.

> Subqueries can be used with the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements along with the operators like =, <, >, >=, <=, IN, BETWEEN, etc.

> There are a few rules that subqueries must follow −

> Subqueries must be enclosed within parentheses.

> A subquery can have only one column in the SELECT clause, unless multiple > >columns are in the main query for the subquery to compare its selected > >columns.

> An ORDER BY command cannot be used in a subquery, although the main query >can use an ORDER BY. The GROUP BY command can be used to perform the same >function as the ORDER BY in a subquery.

> Subqueries that return more than one row can only be used with multiple >value operators such as the IN operator.

> The SELECT list cannot include any references to values that evaluate to a >BLOB, ARRAY, CLOB, or NCLOB.

> A subquery cannot be immediately enclosed in a set function.

> The BETWEEN operator cannot be used with a subquery. However, the BETWEEN >operator can be used within the subquery.

[click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) for more information about sub queries.

Answer (score 1):

Do a self join, something like:

```
select *
from persons p1
left join persons p2 on p2.lastname = p1.middlename
where p1.firstname = 'megaman'
```